# Shadowbox doesn't load current URL

Tags: javascript, html, image, gallery, shadowbox

i'm using a simple image gallery with shadowbox integrated.
This is the normal script.

```
 <div id="gallery">
            <div id="panel">
            <p><a id="showimg" href="images/image_01.jpg" rel="shadowbox">
                <img id="largeImage" src="images/image_01.jpg" />
                </a></p>
            <div id="description">1st image description</div>
            </div>

            <div id="thumbs">
                <img src="images/image_01.jpg" alt="1st image description" />
                <img src="images/image_02.jpg" alt="2nd image description" />
                <img src="images/image_03.jpg" alt="3rd image description" />
                <img src="images/image_04.jpg" alt="4th image description" />
                <img src="images/image_05.jpg" alt="5th image description" />
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>

        <script>

        $('#thumbs').delegate('img','click', function(){
            $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
            $('#description').html($(this).attr('alt'));
        });

        </script>
```

I noticed that the url from the large image was never changing, therefore i added another line on the script to change the href all the time the mouses chamges the image.

```
<script>

$('#thumbs').delegate('img','click', function(){
    $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
    $('#description').html($(this).attr('alt'));
    $('#showimg').attr('href', $(this).attr('src'));
});

</script>
```

I don't know if it's correct but when i pass the mouse hover the images the URL is always different now, but SHADOWBOX loads always the same image (the first one).

A little help please!

Answer (score 0):

Try use this syntax :

html(put class to each images in list):

```
<div id="thumbs">
<img class="imglist" src="images/image_01_thumb.jpg" alt="1st image description" />
</div>
```

js:

```
$('.imglist').on('click','img', function(e){

e.stopPropagation(); or e.preventDefault();

       $('#largeImage').attr('src',$(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large'));
            $('#description').html($(this).attr('alt'));
            $('#showimg').attr('href', $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb', 'large'));

         });
```

Comment: What do you mean with "Try to write this method e.stopPropagation() or e.preventDefault()" ?

I never coded Javascript :/

Comment: try first and if nothing changes then second

Comment: Sorry, but nothing happened. the large image not even has changed

Comment: what means this $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb','large')) ?

Comment: I already had changed... forget the replace... It would only replace a text that i don't use it anymore.

It's going to atribute the src from the #thumbs to the src from the #largeimage.

And i must use the #thumbs instead of the .imglist cause the function can't get the img tag!